# Why /0(\.\d+)?|1/.test('0.') return true?

Tags: javascript, regex

Even `/0(\.\d+)?|1/.test('...0.0.0')`  return `true`... I just want to get a RegExp to test numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: Please provide sample data for both the positive and negative cases.  Note that `0.0.0` is not a valid number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Well, the reason it's returning true is because it's finding a match in your given text.

```
/0(\.\d+)?|1/
```

The regex above will find any `1`,`0` or `0.d+` in any place in the given text. So for `...0.0.0`, it's matching the first `0.d+` it finds. In this case it's `0.0`.

Similarly, for the case in your title `0.`. Your regex matches the first `0` it finds, ignoring the `.`.

#### What you need to look at adding is *anchor* tags. So you could try the following:

```
/^((0(\.\d+)?)|1)$/
```

**`^` - indicating the start of a string**

**`$` - indicating the end of a string**

This makes sure that edge cases like `0.` and `...0.0.0` are handled correctly

```js
[
  '...0.0.0',
  '0',
  '0.',
  '0.12546',
  '0.0.0',
  '1',
  '2'
].forEach(exampleString => console.log(exampleString, /^((0(\.\d+)?)|1)$/.test(exampleString)))
```

*When working with Regex, I would highly suggest working with a regex builder like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/)*

Comment: The regexp will find `1`, `0` and `0.d+` (not just `1` and `0.d`), that's why it also matches the `0.` in the title.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't match `0.` but it will most definitely match `0` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the original regexp, not your solution (originally you had only `1` or `0.d` when explaining what the original regexp was finding)

Comment: Ahh, you're perfectly correct. I see where my misunderstanding was, I thought you meant that the regex would match `0.` as a whole - instead of just `0` in `0.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor the regexp with `^` and `$`, otherwise it matches if the pattern can be found anywhere in the string.

```js
console.log(/^(0(\.\d+)?|1)$/.test('...0.0.0'));
console.log(/^(0(\.\d+)?|1)$/.test('0.1'));
console.log(/^(0(\.\d+)?|1)$/.test('2.3'));
```